# Disable review icon in top bar during ban

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review-queues, top-bar

I entered a review ban period this morning. I noticed that a long-time annoyance of mine has been fixed -- if I click the review icon in the top bar, it says

> There are no review queues available to you

That's nice! Now I remember I'm in a ban with just one click.

This shows the page is already aware I am in a ban. Otherwise it could not show the modal text. Since it has this information, can the icon indicate visually that a ban is in effect? Perhaps a paler gray color. Or an overlaid slash mark over the icon. This would save from having to click at all.

I also noticed that the icon sometimes highlights, drawing attention to itself. But that is useless, because I can't do any reviews. Should the highlight be entirely disabled during a ban?

Comment: The click initiates a call to the backend, which returns that HTML for the popup. The initial page load doesn't know you are in a ban.

Comment: @Oded well that's kyboshed that idea. Out of interest, why does it highlight?

Comment: @Bugs - likely because there are reviews in the queue (the highlight is general - not user specific at this point).

Comment: @Oded one idea in my mind you call same function at page load time and check if you get same text then hide top icon with jquery. That's it very simple.

Comment: @ImBS - sure, very simple. Only then we call it on every load of every page of the site instead of only when someone clicks the icon. Which is the difference between tens of millions of calls to it a day and a few orders of magnitude less calls. Which has an effect on the database and web server and... At our scale, it becomes less simple than you think.

Comment: @Oded hmm as your thinking it will take so much load on server. stackexchange is very big company so have to add this feature so users cannot face this unwanted icon and text.

Comment: @Rha - it isn't the same check, and has a much lower relative cost (in terms of computational resources). There's a big difference between "can you review" and "are there any review items available for you". The two depend on vastly different things.

Comment: Or for that matter, "are you under a review ban". The point is - it is relatively expensive, it is an extra check that we would have to make on every page load, even though it only effects a very minor number of people.

Comment: To give a bit more context to what @Oded said there's currently 147 users banned from review on SO - the majority of which are one-off 2 day bans. I don't see how special casing those (especially if it adds overhead to each page load) is of any benefit when one would hope someone can remember there's no point clicking it for two days.

Comment: @Rhayene - access to review queues is dependent on reputation. That's a quick check on an object that's in memory (the current user). Being banned from review is an extra check - "is the current person banned from review".

Comment: If this is indeed a "long time annoyance" for you (as you noted), I would suggest you focus on *not getting banned*, and worry less about what the top bar looks like when you are. :)

Comment: @JeffLoughlin That's fair, though the review system is imperfect, and everyone gets banned... but given Oded's actual numbers, I now see that the scale of the issue doesn't warrant changing the site's behavior.

Comment: @JonClements Review bans are enacted on relatively high level users who are actively working to improve the site for no reward, right? So the low number affected may be grossly under-representing their value and importance to the site.

Comment: @Robert that's a very weird reasoning you have there: 1. that "high level users" actively work to improve the site, 2. that they do for no reward, 3. that the proportion of users is somehow skewed towards "high level users". I would like to know from where you got that information. (note, that until you have 2k, 3k, you effectively can't participate in any of the queues, so if some comparison has to be done, it has to be against the 2/3kers which, btw, are just 64k users).

Comment: @Braiam I haven't checked but I'm pretty sure 2k+ is high compared to the average visitor. I can't think of any reason for participating in the review queue other than to improve the site, and I am unaware of any reward for doing so. Perhaps my understanding is incorrect.

Comment: @Robert There are also badge rewards for doing reviews (3 per queue).

Comment: @DanLowe I forgot about that. I was just trying to make the point that the people affected by review bans are in general doing a very helpful thing for SE, so measures that improve their experience might have a much bigger effect on the site than is suggested by the small number.

Comment: @Robert of course is relatively high compared with the average visitor: [over 85% of all visitors don't have an account](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/03/09/anyone-actually-visit-stack-overflows-home-page/).

Comment: @Braiam Yes, that's why I thought it was a reasonably safe claim without looking up the numbers.

Comment: @Robert which is why I brought the numbers up to demonstrate that it's meaningless claim. Of course that the users that have power on the site would be a minority, as earning such power requires them to invest effort on the site, which not many do.

Comment: @Braiam Do we disagree on something? Sorry I'm not understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of the release of our [new review suspension notification system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351118/improved-experience-for-users-with-review-suspensions), users who are in a review suspension will no longer see the indicator when there are items to review during the duration of their suspension. They will see the indicator light up one time to draw their attention to the suspension but after that notice has been seen, the indicator will remain dark.

If you run into any issues with this, please let us know!